# Using Z3 wit Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, z3py

I am trying to run Z3 (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) from Google Colaboratory with no luck so far.

I can install it properly using `!apt-get install z3`.

But the Python bindings don't seem to be present.

```
import z3
print(z3.get_version_string())
```

fails
`AttributeError: module 'z3' has no attribute 'get_version_string'`

Answer (score 0):

The Debian Z3 packages are from 2015. I don't think that function existed by then. You need a more recent version of Z3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and install it successfully.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/169gVnbiAjnhCo3AMHxyh-iSZShqYkt3T